# Issue with importing TextExplainer from eli5.lime package relating to deprecated 'itemfreq' function

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats, lime, eli5

I am working on a BERT model for text classification and wish to use TextExplainer for model interpretation. However, when loading the library eli5.lime I receive the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'itemfreq' from 'scipy.stats'
```

It appears that `scipy.stats.itemfreq` is deprecated and was removed from the latest version of the scipy package. Anyone come across this issue? I note the suggestion is to use `np.unique(…, return_counts=True)` instead, however, this means updating samplers.py (which I have tried, but came across another indexing error).

Wondering if anyone has come across this one?

Comment: Have you tried the change in https://github.com/eli5-org/eli5/pull/30/files?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
def monkeypath_itemfreq(sampler_indices):
   return zip(*np.unique(sampler_indices, return_counts=True))

scipy.stats.itemfreq=monkeypath_itemfreq
```

Comment: Despite your code sample solving the original problem, it is important to describe in more detail how it solves that problem.